# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *' to parameter of type 'NSCalendar *'?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nsdate, nscalendar, ios8.1

Let me first say I didn't write this code; it was from the Calendar API written by *tinyFool* in 2010.  As such, it did what it was supposed to do before Apple deprecated CFGregorianDate; now, I'm trying to convert it to the recommended NSCalendar. If you need more relevant code that I haven't supplied, let me know and I'll post it.

I have two statements that appear in several places:

```
    [calendarViewDelegate monthChanged: currentMonthDate viewLeftTop:self.frame.origin height:height];
    [calendarViewDelegate beforeMonthChange:self willto: currentMonthDate];
```

which are giving me the following warning:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *' to parameter of type 'NSCalendar *'

This is the delegate definition:

```
@protocol CalendarViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) selectDateChanged:(NSCalendar *) selectDate;
- (void) monthChanged:(NSCalendar *) currentMonth viewLeftTop:(CGPoint)viewLeftTop height:(float)height;
- (void) beforeMonthChange:(CalendarView *) calendarView willto:(NSCalendar *) currentMonth;
@end
```

Delegates are one of my weak points; for some reason I can't seem to understand them, although I understand what their purpose is.  When I look in my code for *monthChanged*, I find nothing!  So my question is: why is the author using this code if it doesn't do anything?  And how do I change the code to remove the warning, which is affecting the correct operation of the affected methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (void) monthChanged:(NSCalendar *) currentMonth viewLeftTop:(CGPoint)viewLeftTop height:(float)height;` expects an `NSCalendar` as the first arg and you are passing a `NSDate`. Either you are passing a date when you should be passing a calendar or the delegate method should be updated to take a date arg and not an NSCalendar argument. Did you write those delegate methods?

If Self is a `NSCalendar` then probably should be called

`[calendarViewDelegate monthChanged:self viewLeftTop:self.frame.origin height:height];`

Else if you meant to pass an `NSDate`

```
@protocol CalendarViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) selectDateChanged:(NSDate *) selectDate;
- (void) monthChanged:(NSDate *) currentMonth viewLeftTop:(CGPoint)viewLeftTop height:(float)height;
- (void) beforeMonthChange:(CalendarView *) calendarView willto:(NSDate *) currentMonth;
@end
```

**UPDATE**

Example implementation of a delegate method in the delegate if say MYView needs to show an alert every time date changes

```
@interface MYView ()<CalendarViewDelegate>
@end
@implementation MYView
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.calendarView = [[CalendarView alloc] init];
    self.calendarView.delegate = self;
}
- (void) monthChanged:(NSDate *) currentMonth viewLeftTop:(CGPoint)viewLeftTop height:(float)height{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"date changed" andBlahBlah];
    [alert show];
}
@end
```

Comment: I didn't write the delegate methods; as a matter of fact, I can't find them in the entire app!  (I can't find *any* code for those methods!  That's what's got me confused...

Comment: Delegate methods don't have to be implemented. These are listed as optional so there may be no code that uses them. The warning is just a warning that you are passing different types. Just either rewrite the delegate method signatures to take an NSDate or when you call the method pass in an NSCalendar

Comment: `CalendarView ` notifies it delegate that stuff was changed. If no other object cares then there is no need to implement the delegate methods. If say `MyView` wants to show the user an alert when date changes then `MyView` would do `calendarView.delegate = self` and then you would write code to show an alert when `MyView` implements those delegate methods